# Facing issue in navigation bar

Tags: html, css, web, frontend

**index.html
**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <!-- <header>
        <img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" >
        <nav>
            <ul class="nav__links">
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="shop.html">Shop</a></li>
                <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="cart.html"><i class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header> -->

    <section id="header">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" class="logo" alt="" ></a>

        <div>
            <ul id="navbar">
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="shop.html">Shop</a></li>
                <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="cart.html"><i class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        
    </section>
    
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

** styl.css [website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcseI.png)
**

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=League+Spartan:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Spartan', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height:64px;
    color: black;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 46px;
    line-height:54px;
    color: black;
}

h4 {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: black;
}

h6 {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 12px;
}

p {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #465b52;
    margin: 15px 0 20px 0;
}

.section-p1 {
    padding: 40px 80px;
}

.section-m1 {
    margin: 40px 0;
}

body{
    width: 100px;
}


/* Header Start */

#header{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: centre;
    padding: 20px 80px;
    background-color: burlywood;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);  
}

#navbar{
    display:flex;
    align-items: centre;
    justify-content: centre;
}

#navbar li{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

#navbar li a{
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

#navbar li a:hover {
    color: brown;
}
```

I HAVE CREATED THIS NAVIGATION BAR TILL NOW BUT I'M FACING FEW ISSUES IN THIS
WHY MY NAVIGATION IS NOT FULLY COLOURED AND NAVITION BUTTONS LIKE HOME ETC. ARE NOT DISPLAYED ON THE RIGHT HAND SIDE? HOW CAN I SOLVE THIS ISSUE? PLZ HELP! I HAVE ATTACHED A PICTURE OF HOW MY WEBSITE LOOKS TILL NOW.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I deleted the above lines as they were irrelevant and unnecessary.

Then,

***body{width: 100px;}***

this is the line, for this line, your navigation bar is not fully colored, delete this line.

Then,

***justify-content: centre ;***

first of all, you spelled it wrong, it's "**center**" not"**centre**"

I changed that above line into this  and it's done, now your navigation buttons are displaying on the right-hand side

***justify-content: right ;***

****You only need these lines, delete the remaining lines from your code****

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=League+Spartan:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Spartan', sans-serif;
}


/* I deleted the above lines as they were irrelevant and unnecessary */



/* body{
    width: 100px;
} */                       /* line removed */


/* Header Start */

#header{
    display: flex;
 /* align-items: center;*/        /* line removed */
   
    justify-content: right;      /* new line added */
    
    padding: 20px 80px;
    background-color: burlywood;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);  
}

#navbar{
    display:flex;
    align-items: centre;
    justify-content: centre;
}

#navbar li{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

#navbar li a{
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

#navbar li a:hover {
    color: brown;
}
```